# I am unable to do deployment to Jboss 6.x eap from jenkins job?

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, jboss, jenkins-plugins

I am using deploy plugin to do deployment from Jenkins to Jboss 7.
I follwed the below steps as mentioned in google group to make it work

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/9Ghwuwdebxw

But i able to do deployment from Jenkins windows machine to Jboss windows machine.
But same is not working from Linux(Jenkins) to Linux(Jboss) machines?
After build is success it is not showing any step related to post build actions.

channel stopped

Finished: SUCCESS

Can anyone please help on this? Thanks in advance.